# nohup process keep shutting down

Tags: php, linux, exec, nohup

I am trying to run 10.000 processes to create asterisks phone accounts. 
This is to stress-test our Asterisk server.

I called with php an exec() function to create a Linux command.

```
nohup /usr/src/pjproject-2.3/pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --id=sip:%s@13.113.163.3 --registrar=sip:127.0.0.1:25060 --realm=* --username=%s --password=123456 --local-port=%s --null-audio --no-vad --max-calls=32 --no-tcp >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null & $(echo -ne \'\r\')"
```

Everything works perfect and the script does exactly what I am expecting.
But here comes also the next problem; after creating the 10.000 accounts, the processes are suddenly all getting killed.

**Why is this?**

Isn't it so that the nohup function keeps the processes alive?
After calling the nohup function I am also calling the disown function.

Thank you for the help

[edit]
I also tried this project with the function screen, the screen functions work like a charm, but the problem is the cpu usage. To create 10.000 screens, makes a linux server go nuts, this is why I choose for nohup.

The full php code:

```
<?php

# count
$count_screens = 0;

# port count start
$port_count = 30000; 

# register accounts number
$ext_number = 1000; 

# amount of times you want this loop to go
$min_accounts = 0;    
$max_accounts = 1000;          

Class shell {   

    const CREATE_SESSION  =    'screen -dmS stress[%s]';     
    const RUN_PJSUA       =    'screen -S stress[%s] -p 0 -rX stuff "nohup /usr/src/pjproject-2.3/pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --id=sip:%s@13.113.163.3 --registrar=sip:127.0.0.1:25060 --realm=* --username=%s --password=123456 --local-port=%s --null-audio --no-vad --max-calls=32 --no-tcp >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null &"';     
    const DISOWN_PJSUA    =    'screen -S stress[%s] -p 0 -rX stuff "disown -l $(echo -ne \'\r\')"';   

    public function openShell($count_screens) {   

        # creating a new screen to make the second call

        $command = sprintf(static:: CREATE_SESSION, $count_screens);  
        $string  = exec($command); 
        return var_dump($string);     

    } 

    public function runPJSUA($count_screens, $ext_number, $ext_number, $port_count) {  

        # register a new pjsua client 

        $command = sprintf(static:: RUN_PJSUA, $count_screens, $ext_number, $ext_number, $port_count);
        $string  = exec($command);  
        usleep(20000);  
        return var_dump($string); 

    }

    public function disownPJSUA($count_screens) {  

        # register a new pjsua client 

        $command = sprintf(static:: DISOWN_PJSUA, $count_screens); 
        $string  = exec($command);    
        return var_dump($string); 

    }

}  

while ($min_accounts < $max_accounts) {

    $shell = new shell(); 

    if ($count_screens == '0') {
        $count_screens++;
        echo $shell->openShell($count_screens); 
    } else {
        $count_screens = 1;
    }

    $port_count++; 
    $ext_number++; 
    $min_accounts++;  

    echo $shell->runPJSUA($count_screens, $ext_number, $ext_number, $port_count);
    echo $shell->disownPJSUA($count_screens);  

}
```

?>

Comment: Including the PHP code for executing the mentioned command line and disowning the process can certainly make things clearer.

Comment: have edited the question with the full php code

Answer (score 0):

Pjsua is relatively heavy application, definitely too heavy to run 10000 instances, not intended for this kind of testing. As you are configuring it for 32 calls even running out of ports would be a problem (there are two ports per call reserved plus port for SIP). If you want to stay with pjsua you might at least optimize test by configuring multiple accounts for single pjsua instance. It might be limited by command line length, but ~30 accounts per instance might work.

Comment: I found that out, first I tried with different screens, but this takes to much memory and CPU. Now I tried with different processes in the background. It works fine, it registers almost 100%, but after finishing the script it closes the background processes. I am now not at the office, so I can't check it, but I think I found the solution. Apparently, pjsua has a server idle time function that kills the inactive account after 10 minutes. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Pjsua does not have any timer of this kind.

Comment: Our client really needs to see the 10.000 accounts, if it not works we should maybe find another client like pjaua; got any suggestions :)

Comment: SIPp is more suitable for heavy SIP testing. Also, note that no tool can simulate real-life situations perfectly. For example, I had once problem with depleted memory pool for ARP routes and while SIPp can simulate 10k SIP registrations, delays, message reordering, incorrect authentication - it cannot trigger this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am going to test a few more things on Monday and if that is not working than it will become SIPp. Thank you again :)

Comment: I wanted to give an update @tmsz seems that 10.000 accounts are now working. Tried it a different way. Apparently 1 pjsua account can host 6 SIP account. This way I made it work for the 10.000 account.